# PHP MySQL visitors best way to count and detect

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to count the visits to each page in the site and detect who is online

My solution

---

table for all sessions of visitors

```
-----------------------------------------------
|id | sessionid | last_active | member_id | ip|
-----------------------------------------------
```

the member_id is -1 for none members and the member id for mebers

another table for each click for unique sessionid

```
----------------------------------
|id | sessionid | url| visit_date|
----------------------------------
```

and the total site visitors is the sessions table rows count and each page visits count is the number of rows where the url of this page

---

1. the url may has problem if we do an operation on the page [adding comments ...] the url will change and new visit is inserted !!! shall i use the id of page?
2. after years for a common website the sessions table will be crowded what can we do? shall we clean it periodically but what will happen to the total count or its not important? also the visits table will be crowded will this effect the performance? what else can i do?

   ---

OK this is my solution and my questions what is your suggestions and improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Sessions expire, and so should the data from your table. You can probably hook into the session garbage collector/close handler to expire data from your table.

Or use db-based sessions and unify your sessions and online member count data in one place. That is the best solution, IMO, so long as you're not dealing with huge amounts of traffic.

Comment: there is no problem about db based session but the analytics for the site will be destroyed when session is destroied?? what is alternative??

Comment: The default session cleanup function has no hooks available (unfortunately, seems like it'd have been a good idea to have some). - but you can roll your own session handling complex